# jQuery table replace

Tags: jquery, html-table

We have a table:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td width="10">1</td>
    <td>text 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="10">2</td>
    <td>text 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="10">3</td>
    <td>text 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="10">4</td>
    <td>text 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="10">5</td>
    <td>text 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="10">6</td>
    <td>text 6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="10">7</td>
    <td>text 7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="10">8</td>
    <td>text 8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="10">9</td>
    <td>text 9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="10">10</td>
    <td>text 10</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

We update this table by throwing into each `<tr>` **3** `<td>`, each `<td>` with `width="10"` attribute must be deleted.

It must look like:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>text 1</td>
    <td>text 2</td>
    <td>text 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>text 4</td>
    <td>text 5</td>
    <td>text 6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>text 7</td>
    <td>text 8</td>
    <td>text 9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>text 10</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can we do this?

Comment: What have you done so far? Maybe you can post your jQuery code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove those elements with an [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) before wrapping, like this:

```
$("table tr td[width='10']").remove();
var elems = $("table tr td").unwrap();
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i+=3) {
  elems.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<tr></tr>");
}​
```

[You can play with it here](http://jsfiddle.net/trGzV/1/)

Comment: @Happy - The demo above does :) What behavior are you seeing? This should be pretty straight-forward...